# pig how to sort tuple by one of bag value

Tags: sorting, apache-pig

I have a data set structured like this: `{movie:chararry, year:int, weight:float, actor:chararray}`

I am trying to find out the move with highest weights in each year. So I group the set by year and movie, then I got the following set:

```
{group: (year:int, movie:chararray), movies:{(movie:chararry, year:int, weight:float, actor:chararray)}}
```

My question is how could I sort the set by one of bag value, weight?. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested statements in FOREACH.

```
inpt = load '...../data.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (movie:chararry, year:int, weight:float, actor:chararray);

grp = group inpt by (year, movie);

srt = foreach grp {
    by_wright = ORDER inpt BY weight;
    generate group, by_wright;
};
```